# Best practices for designing registers into a peripheral that will be accessed by C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, fpga, specifications

I am designing a serial port peripheral in an FPGA that will have memory mapped registers visible to my processor.

Does C/C++ (I use both) guarantee that writing to a memory location will not also result in a read from the same location?

I ask because the read would read-back different data than was just written, and because the read has side effects (it pulls the next byte from the queue).

I am trying to share a single memory location for TX and RX data, to minimize the size of my decoding logic.

Related question: Does C/C++ guarantee that a single memory location read will always be a single read, and not somehow end up being multiple reads.  Long experience says yes, but I wonder what the spec says.

Note: I always declare pointers to peripheral registers to be volatile, like this:
    volatile uint32_t * p_reg;

Comment: No, I don't believe that the C++ Standard guarantees any such thing. You might want to read up on the `volatile` qualifier, but I don't really see this as relevant.

Comment: I think `volatile` *might* guarantee this. But otherwise I'm pretty sure it doesn't, since it has no effect on the abstract machine.

Comment: jeez, this got downvoted. Its a great question. Maybe the question would be better stated as 'best practice for reading and writing locations mapped to physical peripherals'

Comment: @pm100, changing the title would be good, but I'm more interested in the best practices for designing registers into a peripheral.  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: There is standard extension [iohw.h](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1021.pdf), but I haven't seen an implementation that implements it... As it is a standard, if you are designing your own interface, it's better to follow any kind of specification. In my practice with stm32 I use [keil's cmsis](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Driver/html/index.html) and they use macros and access bits with bit operations `&` |`,  for example [here](https://github.com/micropython/stm32lib/blob/vendor/CMSIS/STM32F0xx/Include/stm32f091xc.h#L707).

Answer (score 1):

There is really no such thing as a write to a memory location in either C or C++. There's just code and memory with the compiler deciding whether to read or write to memory to make the code do what the code is required to do as it thinks is necessary. Your platform *might* make `volatile` do what you want or it might not, but that's a platform-specific question.

If you write `j=1;` and you have a platform where constants other than zero are expensive but increments are cheap, the implementation is free to treat that as `j=0; ++j;` if it wants.

There have even been real world cases where operations that looked like pure reads actually wrote to memory. Nothing in either the C nor C++ standards prohibit this.

You can check your compiler's documentation around `volatile` to see if it does what you need. If not, look into inline assembly code. If this is something sensible to do on your platform, a decent compiler should provide a good way to do it.

Comment: @NXT There are several methods. The most common is to use a function or macro provided by the platform, typically through inline assembly code, that's guaranteed to provide the behavior you want. Some platforms have platform-specific guarantees about `volatile` or special types that are "super-volatile" and guarantee particular things you need. Obviously, people want to make usable platforms so they try to provide you easy ways to get the guaranteed semantics you're likely to need. (If this is reasonable on your platform, your compiler should provide you easy ways to get it.)